# ASP MVC import CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am trying to include a CSS file into my view.

The view is strongly typed and has a List Scaffold Template, it is linked to a master page which itself is linked to a css file and works fine for the master slide but when trying to link the view to a seperate css file I cant as I cannot include tags.

Anybody know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/YOURSTYLESHEET.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Hi Dampe, Thanks you for your suggestion but I need abit more, I have tried that in the view in both the contentPlaceHolder and outside of it and it hasnt worked out. I know that usually the <link tag should go in the <head> of the html, but I am unable to add that in the MVC view.

Comment: It's true that VS was showing some green underline saying that I can't include link inside a link, but that's a nonsense. I builded it, line disappeared and my link to css file is showing in View source of my view. Please share your code with us, so we can see where the problem might be.

Comment: Btw: I am not saying, that including css stylesheet in a middle of html markup is good way, but it's possible and browsers render it just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You should add a new content place holder in your site.master page in the head tags, i always have one called "HeadContent" which i use for inclusion of scripts and css that i only want on individual pages.

Comment: <head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/Site.css"  type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageInformation" runat="server">
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/ForumStyle.css"  type="text/css" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head> Is what I have tried with adding that content placeholder in the view but it doesnt seem to be working, is what i have correct?